# How to make parameter of function act like variable string methods

Tags: python, methods, parameter-passing

I want to make function that gets parameter and use it as a method in it. Here is what I'm trying to do with string.upper() .lower() methods.

```
def caps_lock(case, string):
    print(string.case())


string = 'Hello World'

caps_lock(upper, string)
caps_lock(lower, string)
```

expected result

```
>HELLO WORLD
>hello world
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
def caps_lock(func, string):
    print(func(string))


string = 'Hello World'

caps_lock(str.upper, string)
caps_lock(str.lower, string)
```

Or:

```
def caps_lock(thunk):
    print(thunk())


string = 'Hello World'
caps_lock(string.upper)
caps_lock(string.lower)
```

This is also an option, technically, but I do not recommend it:

```
def caps_lock(func_name, string):
    print(getattr(string, func_name)())


string = 'Hello World'
caps_lock("upper", string)
caps_lock("lower", string)
```

In all of these cases, nothing about the `caps_lock` function forces it to *only* uppercase or lowercase the string; you can pass any arbitrary function and it'll print the result of running that function on the string.

Note also that having to pass the function into `caps_lock` makes it not really save you any effort over just calling the function yourself:

```
string = 'Hello World'
print(string.upper())
print(string.lower())
```

If you wanted a function that specifically only uppercased or lowercased a string before printing it, you'd have to specify those functions inside the body of `caps_lock` like this:

```
def caps_lock(on, string):
    print(string.upper() if on else string.lower())


string = 'Hello World'
caps_lock(True, string)
caps_lock(False, string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def do(obj,method,*params):
    getattr(obj,method)(*params)
    
class Testobj:
    def bla(self,*args):
        print("bla")
        print(args)

do(Testobj(),"bla",1,2,3,4)
```

#prints:
bla
(1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).